# How to use injection via GIN with UiBinder and Widgets?

Tags: gwt, dependency-injection, uibinder, gwt-gin

I'm using GWT 2.4 with gwt-platform 0.7 and gin 1.5.0.

I've built a library for dynamic (live) translation of my GWT application. So every widget will get notified when the `LocaleChangeEvent` gets fired and then ask my `TranslationDictionary` to get the new String to display.

The widgets actually look like this:

```
public class LocaleAwareLabel extends Label implements LocaleChangeEventHandler {
    TranslationDictionary dictionary;
    String translationToken;

    public LocaleAwareLabel(TranslationDictionary dictionary, EventBus eventBus, String translationToken) {
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
        this.translationToken = translationToken;
        eventBus.addHandler(LocaleChangeEvent.TYPE, this);
        getCurrentTranslationFromDictionary();
    }

    public void getCurrentTranslationFromDictionary() {
        this.setText(dictionary.getTranslation(translationToken));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocaleChange(LocaleChangeEvent event) {
        getCurrentTranslationFromDictionary();
    }
}
```

As you can see: I can't easily use this widget with UiBinder, at the moment I inject `EventBus` and  `TranslationDictionary` in my `View` and use `@UiField(provided=true)`like this:

```
@UiField(provided=true)
LocaleAwareLabel myLabel;

@Inject
public MyView(TranslationDictionary dictionary, EventBus eventBus) {
    widget = uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);

    myLabel = new LocaleAwareLabel(dictionary, eventBus, "someTranslationToken");
}
```

**What I'd like to have:** Using my widgets without `@UiField(provided=true)`, so I can simply put them inside a `ui.xml` like this:

```
<custom:LocaleAwareLabel ui:field="myLabel" translationToken="someTranslationToken" />
```

I know I can set the `translationToken` via UiBinder using:

```
public void setTranslationToken(String translationToken) {
    this.translationToken = translationToken;
}
```

But then I still have the problem that I can't use a zero-args constructor because of `EventBus` and `TranslationDictionary`. And additionaly I can't call the `getCurrentTranslationFromDictionary()` inside the constructor, because the value of `translationToken` of course gets set after the constructor.

Would be nice if someone can provide a solution, maybe with code examples.

And P.S. I'm a total injection-noob, but from my understanding gin may somehow solve my problem. But I don't know how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible currently, because UiBinder won't ever call into GIN to instantiate widgets. For that you have to use `@UiFactory` methods, or provide already-built instances with `@Uifield(provided=true)`.

There's a request for enhancement already to better integrate the two. You can track it here: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6151

As an alternative, you can `requestStaticInjection` to inject a `Provider` into a `static` field, and call the provider's `get()` from within your constructor:

```
public class LocaleAwareLabel extends Label {
   @Inject Provider<EventBus> eventBusProvider;
   @Inject Provider<TranslationDictionary> dictionaryProvider;

   private final TranslationDictionary dictionary;
   private final EventBus eventBus;
   private final string translationToken;

   @UiConstructor
   public LocaleAwareLabel(String translationToken) {
       this(dictionaryProvider.get(), eventBusProvider.get(), translationToken);
   }

   // For cases where you can use injection, or inject params yourself
   @Inject
   public LocaleAwarelabel(TranslationDictionary dictionary, EventBus eventBus,
           String translationToken) {
       this.dictionary = dictionary;
       this.eventBus = eventBus;
       this.translationToken = translationToken;
   }
```

You might also be interested into GIN's support for Assisted-Inject, to make it easier to write `@UiFactory` methods or initialize `@UiField(provided=true)` fields.

Comment: Thank you. `@UiFactory` looks pretty much the same as `@UiField(provided=true)`. The `@UiConstructor` approach looks more like what I want, but still not perfect! In my head are two other possibilities (but I don't know how to implement them): `1.` I read somewhere about GinUiBinder (from gwt-platform). `2.` From what I've read I thought that gin could provide some kind of factory that automatically injects `EventBus` and `TranslationDictionary` and then just provides the `LocaleAwareLabel(String translationToken)` constructor. Or isn't that possible because of the `@UiConstructor` annotation?

Comment: Forgot to ask: Has static injection some kind of disadvantages? First thought: The method **request**StaticInjection doesn't look like someone really should use it (just for cases of emergency). Second thought was: In Java world `static` is evil (for performance reasons etc.), but I can't imagine how it gets handled in GWT.

Comment: AFAIK, GinUiBinder was an experiment and no longer works with newer versions of GWT (I might be wrong though). The other point is [AssistedInject](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject), but it creates a factory, it doesn't do any magic with your classes. As for `static`, static *state* is evil, whichever the language or platform; in this case it's not really a problem, it just _feels_ bad/odd.

Comment: Thans for your reply. I think I will go with static injection. So I don't have to pollute my View with things that are only meant for the widgets. Or have I forgotten something?

Answer (score 6):

There's currently a little bit of a concept mismatch between Dependency Injection and UiBinder, but the way I currently use it is:

```java
private final Provider<LocaleAwareLabel> labelProvider;

@Inject
public MyView(TranslationDictionary dictionary, 
              EventBus eventBus, 
              Provider<LocaleAwareLabel> labelProvider) {

  this.dictionary = dictionary;
  this.labelProvider = labelProvider;
  initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}

@UiFactory
public LocaleAwareLabel buildLocaleAwareLabel() {
  return labelProvider.get();
}
```

Then I can create as many labels as I want in my ui.xml:

```xml
<g:HTMLPanel>
  <custom:LocaleAwareLabel translationToken="abc"/>
  <custom:LocaleAwareLabel translationToken="xyz"/>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

In the LocaleAwareLabel, I use a setter method for the translation token, and override `onLoad()`:

```java
private String translationToken;

@Inject
public LocaleAwareLabel(TranslationDictionary dictionary, EventBus eventBus) {
  this.dictionary = dictionary;
  initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}

@Override
protected void onLoad() {
  super.onLoad();
  doSomethingWithTheTranslationToken(); // do this here, not in the constructor!
}

public void setTranslationToken(final String translationToken) {
  this.translationToken = translationToken;
}
```

#### Example for AssistedInject

MyView changes to:

```java
private final LocaleAwareLabelFactory labelFactory;

@Inject
public MyView(TranslationDictionary dictionary, 
              EventBus eventBus, 
              LocaleAwareLabelFactory labelFactory) {

  this.dictionary = dictionary;
  this.labelFactory = labelFactory;

  initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}

@UiFactory
public LocaleAwareLabel buildLocaleAwareLabel(final String translationToken) {
  return labelFactory.create(translationToken);
}
```

LocaleAwareLabel:

```java
public interface LocaleAwareLabelFactory {
  LocaleAwareLabel create(final String translationToken);
}

@Inject
public LocaleAwareLabel(TranslationDictionary dictionary, 
                        EventBus eventBus, 
                        @Assisted String translationToken) {

  this.dictionary = dictionary;
  initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
  doSomethingWithTheTranslationToken(); // now you can do it in the constructor!
}
```

In your Gin module, add:

```java
install(new GinFactoryModuleBuilder().build(LocaleAwareLabelFactory.class));
```

Make sure to add guice's assistedinject jar (e.g. guice-assistedinject-snapshot.jar) to your classpath.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it later. I've already asked in the comment to Thomas Broyer's post: What about the GinUiBinder from gwt-platform? I haven't found any real documentation. The name 'sounds' like it could use Gin with UiBinder, but I don't really know...

Comment: @Chris: this is basically the approach I was suggesting with AssistedInject: replace the `Provider` with your factory, add parameters to the `@UiFactory` method (works like `@UiConstructor`) and pass them to the factory.

Comment: Could you please provide an example for that `@AssistedInject` thingy. I can't really imagine what you mean.

Comment: @Benjamin: Ok, I added an example. BTW, there are a few drawbacks to static injection. The official [Guice documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections) says: "This API is not recommended for general use because it suffers many of the same problems as static factories: it's clumsy to test, it makes dependencies opaque, and it relies on global state." You may get into trouble, if multiple modules try to set a different provider on the static field...

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for the AssistedInject idea!

Comment: Looks a little bit nicer than the previous example. But staticInjection is so much shorter. I think I can ignore most of the problems: These are really basic widgets that don't need testing, the TranslationDictionary itself can be tested without staticInjection. For this one dependency I think I can ignore the opaqueness. This global state thingy is the only thing I can't imagine in JavaScript. I'll write a small app and look at the pretty compiled code. One more question: What do you mean "set different providers on the static field"?